# Addition of four-momenta in scattering amplitude of nucleon-anti-nucleon pair in scalar Yakuwa theory

Tags: quantum-field-theory, special-relativity, particle-physics, field-theory, scattering-cross-section

**Intro**

I'm studying QFT using David Tong's lecture notes. In section 3.5 on examples of scattering amplitudes in scalar Yukawa theory, the scattering amplitude $A$ of a nucleon-anti-nucleon scattering event at order $g^2$ is denoted by (eq 3.59):

$$
iA = (-ig)^2 \left[ \frac{i}{(p_1-p_1')^2 - m^2} + \frac{i}{(p_1+p_2)^2 - m^2 + i\epsilon} \right],
$$

with $p_1$, $p_2$ ($p_1'$, $p_2'$) the four-momenta of the incoming (outgoing) nucleon and anti-nucleon with mass M, and m the mass of the virtual meson mediating the interaction, the Feynman diagrams are given below. So one scattering event includes exchange of a virtual meson, while the other includes decay of a nucleon-anti-nucleon pair into a meson which then decays again into a nucleon-anti-nucleon pair. This I all understand.

[image]

Tong then focuses on the denominator of the second term in $A$. He poses that in the center-of-mass frame $\vec{p_1}=-\vec{p_2}$, and therefore the denominator reads $4(M^2+\vec{p_1}^2)-m^2$ (neglecting the $-i\epsilon$ term). The resulting argument is then that at the point where $4(M^2+\vec{p_1}^2)=m^2$ the scattering amplitude of the second term diverges which can be recognized as a resonance in the cross section of a collider experiment at e.g. CERN.

**Question**

What I do not understand is how the condition $\vec{p_1}=-\vec{p_2}$ leads to $4(M^2+\vec{p_1}^2)-m^2$ in the denominator of the second term. According to my (elementary) knowledge of relativistic kinematics there should be no $\vec{p_1}^2$ term in the denominator:

$$
(p_1+p_2)^2 - m^2
= \left[ (M, \vec{p_1}) + (M, \vec{p_2}) \right]^2 - m^2,
$$

after substitution of $\vec{p_2} \rightarrow -\vec{p_1}$:

$$
= \left[ (M, \vec{p_1}) + (M, -\vec{p_1}) \right]^2 - m^2 = \left[ 2(M, \vec{0}) \right]^2 - m^2 = 4M^2 - m^2.
$$

In other words, in the center of mass frame the Mandelstam s-variable $s=(p_1 + p_2)=M^2$, which is in agreement with other sources I have found on the topic.

So where does the $\vec{p_1}^2$ term come from? Am I missing a minus sign somewhere?

Comment: The key to working with relativistic elastic scattering is to know that the quantity that IS conserved is the four momentum. So mathematically, $\sum_{i\text{ before}}p_\mu^i=\sum_{i\text{ after}}p_\mu^i$. Where the $i$ index labels all particles, i.e. $p_\mu$, $q_\mu$...etc. With this and your favourite identities you can work out your question.

Comment: I assume you are alluding to the fact that in terms of relativistic energy conservation $E(p_1)+E(p_2)=E(k)$, where k is the four-momentum of the meson? In that case I can see that $E(p_i)=\sqrt{M^2+\vec{p_i}^2}$ and $E(k)=m^2$ since in the c.o.m. frame $\vec{k}=0$. Also $\vec{p_1}+\vec{p_2}=\vec{k}=0$. Replacing $p_1$ and $p_2$ in $A$ with $E(p_1)$ and $E(p_2)$ leads to $(p_1+p_2)^2=(E(p_1)+E(p_2))^2=(\sqrt{M^2+\vec{p_1}^2} + \sqrt{M^2+\vec{p_2}^2})^2$ and substituting $\vec{p_2} \rightarrow -\vec{p_1}$ gives $(4M^2+4|\vec{p_1}|^2)$ which explains the $\vec{p_1}^2$ term in the denominator.

Comment: Im glad my comment seems to have solved your issue. However, I meant exactly what I said. For instance, in terms of the norm of these vectors, if we denote the total 4-momentum $P_\mu=p_\mu+q_\mu+…$ then my previous eq reads $P_\mu^B = P_\mu^A$, where A and B stands for after and before. Then the norm of this equation is $P_\mu^BP^{\mu B}=P_\mu^A P^{\mu A}$, and you can multiply that out and use the id $p_\mu p^\mu=E^2-\vec{p}^2$ where the sign depends on your metric convention, in my case $(1,-1,-1,-1)$.

Comment: I think I understand your argument but I fail to see how it helps me identify the source of the $\vec{p_1}^2$ term. If I follow your logic and for clarity redefine $p_{\mu}=(E, \vec{p})$, then $P_{\mu}^A = p_{\mu}^1+p_{\mu}^2=(E_1+E_2, \vec{p_1}+\vec{p_2})$ for the nucleon-anti-nucleon pair and $P_{\mu}^B = k_{\mu} = (E_k, \vec{k})$ for the meson. Then using the +--- metric $P_{\mu}^BP^{\mu B} = (E_1+E_2)^2 - (\vec{p_1}+\vec{p_2})^2$ and $P_{\mu}^AP^{\mu A}=E_k^2=m^2$. I can equate these two, but I don't yet see how it answers my original question.

Comment: Ah, I think I figured it out. I was simply confused about the $p_0$ elements. I was under the assumption that always for $c=1$, $p_0=m$, but actually this is only true if $\vec{p}=0$ and in reality $p_0=E=\sqrt{m^2+\vec{p}^2}$. So I was right that in the c.o.m. frame $\vec{p_1}$ and $\vec{p_2}$ cancel each other in $(p_1+p_2)^2$. My mistake was assuming $p_{1,0}=p_{2,0}=M$ when actually $p_{i,0}=E_i=\sqrt{M^2+\vec{p_i}^2}$. Then, using $\vec{p_1}=-\vec{p_2}$ in the c.o.m. frame, it follows that $(p_1+p_2)^2=(E_1+E_2, \vec{p_1}+\vec{p_2})^2=(2\sqrt{M^2+\vec{p_1}^2}, 0)^2=4(M^2+\vec{p_1}^2)$.